# Android Studio Google Cloud Credential Error

Tags: android, android-studio, credentials

While trying to clone a project from my Google Cloud account I entered incorrect password. Every time I click on clone it gives me an Invalid username/password error but I cannot figure out a way to re enter credentials. Please let me know if you know how to reset the saved credentials for Google Cloud in Android Studio.

Regards,
Nisha K

Answer (score 0):

Go into windows control panel / credential manager, and look for the entry for google cloud under 'Generic Credentials".   Remove this, then go back into the clone option and you will get the username /password option again.